# How can I scrape a website without table tag?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

In trying to scrape a certain NBA website, the table class is difficult to be parsed and picked using both BeautifulSoup and pd.read_html()

I used the method below to scrape for the table in the [www.nba.com](http://www.nba.com)

```
stars_url ="https://www.nba.com/stats/players/traditional?Season={}&dir=A&sort=NBA_FANTASY_PTS"`

season = '2010-11' 
url = stars_url.format(season) 
data = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text) 
stat = soup.select("table", class_ ="Crom_table__p1iZz"`)


import pandas as pd 
from io import StringIO 
stat_tr = pd.read_html(StringIO(str(stat)), encoding='utf-8') 
stat_tr
```

the results pull up a calender:

```
[   Sun  Mon  Tues  Wed  Thurs  Fri  Sat
0   31    1     2    3      4    5    6
1    7    8     9   10     11   12   13
2   14   15    16   17     18   19   20?/
3   21   22    23   24     25   26   27
4   28   29    30   31      1    2    3,
Sun  Mon  Tues  Wed  Thurs  Fri  Sat
0   31    1     2    3      4    5    6
1    7    8     9   10     11   12   13
2   14   15    16   17     18   19   20
3   21   22    23   24     25   26   27
4   28   29    30   31      1    2    3]
```

I tried the `soup.find_all()` and `pd.read_html(data.text, match="Crom_table__p1iZz")` in trying to parse through the html to find a table but still resulted in a calender table

*PS: the table(players_traditional_stats) in the website do not have id. so it added a layer of difficulty in finding the table.

Comment: What were you expecting instead?

Comment: I don't see `Crom_table__p1iZz` anywhere in the HTML of that page. Use `View Source` in the browser to see what `requests.get()` returns.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly doubt that there's a tool for this in any of your libraries but you could write the parser yourself for the table, essentially trying to convert it in some kind of CSV.

If you replace the spaces with commas, remove the rows containing the names of the weeks and then delete all the random characters hanging around you'll have a clean set of data. You can then split it in tables of 7 elements to separate the weeks and you'll be all good !

Answer (score 0):

This will print out all the tables found on the webpage. If the desired table is not in the output, it's possible that the data is loaded dynamically using JavaScript. In such cases, you might need to use a tool like Selenium to interact with the website and retrieve the data after it has been loaded.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

stars_url = "https://www.nba.com/stats/players/traditional?Season={}&dir=A&sort=NBA_FANTASY_PTS"
season = '2010-11'
url = stars_url.format(season)
data = requests.get(url)
tables = pd.read_html(data.text)

for i, table in enumerate(tables):
print(f"Table {i + 1}")
print(table)
print("\n")
```

Comment: Thank Your for the code. I used Selenium to scrap the web and it worked

Comment: If I may add a context to the above issue. I have gotten the table i wanted by using selenuim but another problem i encountered was that the tables are paginated. How do i scrap the rest of the table from other pages